# Array in another array in Php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm newbie in php I would like to make an array in another array

My array:

```
array:3 [▼
0 => User {#621 ▼
-id: 1
-firstname: "mathiew"
-partner: "anne"
}
1 => Relation  ▼
-id: 1
-child: "julie"
}
2 => Relation  ▼
-id: 2
-child: "karla"
}
]
```

Here is my code

```
foreach ($relations as $relation_id) {
        $user[] = $relation_id;
    }
```

And I would like to have Relation on User like this

```
 array:3 [▼
 0 => User {#621 ▼
-id: 1
-firstname: "mathiew"
-partner: "anne"
  1 => Relation  ▼
  -id: 1
  -child: "julie"
   }
   2 => Relation  ▼
  -id: 2
  -child: "karla"
  }
  } 
]
```

Comment: That's an an ambiguous example. What when there are more users? Format of arrays/objects corrupted.

Comment: Use `var_export()` to show reproducible outputs. Also show class dependencies. Make sure you have read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Thanks for reply. User is related to both relations. I try with var_export() but it's not working :/

Comment: Is that how the array comes, mixed with users and relatives in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very general but may show you the basic of array handling in `PHP`:

You can define user as:

```
$u = array("id" => 1, "firstname", "partner" => "anne", "relations" => array());
```

You can see we define empty array inside `user`. Now you can add element to that inner array with `$u["relations"][]` so if you have loop of relations:

```
$relations = array(array("id" => 1, "child" =>  "julie"), array("id" => 2, "child" =>  "karla"));
foreach ($relations as $relation) {
    $u["relations"][] = $relation;
}
```

Hope that help and feel free to ask!